# Finding columns that contain values based on another column

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
Step    1   2   3
1       5   10  6
2       5   11  5
3       5   13  9
4       5   15  10
5       13  18  10
6       15  20  10
7       17  23  10
8       19  25  10
9       21  27  13
10      23  30  7
```

I would like to retrieve the columns that satisfy one of the following conditions: if `step 1 = step 4` or `step 4 = step 8`. In this case, column 1 and 3 should be retrieved. Column 1 because the value at Step 1 = value at step 4 (i.e., 5), and for column 3, the value at step 4 = value at step 8 (i.e., 10).

I don't know how to do that in R. Can someone help me please?

Comment: @akrun I found it really difficult to write a short title that explains what I exactly want.

Comment: Can you please describe in the post about what you meant by `step1 = step 4`  Is that values in column 'step' equal to other column? or is it the duplicate elements?  `df1[sapply(df1, function(x) max(rle(x)$lengths)>=4),]`

Comment: or may be `df1[sapply(df1, function(x)  length(unique(x[1:4])) == 1 | length(unique(x[4:8]))),]`

Comment: Can you please add an 'expected output' table so we see what the final results should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the column indices by the following code:

```
df[1, -1] == df[4, -1] | df[4, -1] == df[8, -1]

#     X1    X2   X3
# 1 TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

---

```
# data
df <- structure(list(Step = 1:10, X1 = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 13L, 15L, 
17L, 19L, 21L, 23L), X2 = c(10L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 
25L, 27L, 30L), X3 = c(6L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 
7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```